I need help with constant power load but with AC source on LTspice
I'm trying to simulate a circuit on LTspice. It's a train system and since I only know how much power each train consumes (because it's constant), I've decided to represent the loads (train) with bi source on LTspice with AC source, but it just doesn't work. Can you guys please help?


Can you expand on "does not work"? How does it behave and how does it differ from what you expect?

Hi Winny! thank you so much for your answer. The voltage and current are wayyyyyyyyy off. The voltage across the load (my train) is like mV something but i expected it (theoratically) about 15000-16000 something V. (rms)

So your constant power load isn't working as you expect it to? I haven't done it for AC, but for DC, this works: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/449306/constant-power-load-spice-model. The limit function is usable to not have LTspice go from pA at one end to GA in the other in order to try to satisfy the consant part.

Ive tried it for DC and it worked to. But my power source is an AC source

Yes, so the power will only be constant over one half AC-period (good PF), but not instantaneously constant (terrible PF). You need to low-pass away that behavior somehow. The possibilities are endless. Perhaps cheat with SAMPLEHOLD function to only update on the zero-crossing and maintain the resistance/current value for the entire period?

Do you know the phase relationship between the voltage source and the load?
